# Can a function return an Interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, return-value

New to typescript here. Is it possible to have a function that returns the interface to be used for a variable declaration?
And if "yes" how can this be done?
A use case (not working) would be the following:

```
let someVar: desiredFunction(name);

const desiredFunction = (name:string) => (name === 'name1') ? Interface1 : Interface2;
```

Comment: Do you have a particular use case ? Some times this kind of issues can be solved by generics !

Comment: [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html) are like functions on types.

Comment: What is your use case? What is so special to this variable that its type is not known when you write the code?

Comment: Smells like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). 1. TS only handles *compiletime* code. Not runtime. 2. Even if it was runtime - how in the world do you expect this code to work? You get `Interface1` or `Interface2` and *you don't know which*. Yet you're supposed to be able to use `someVar` yet you cannot safely do because, again, you don't know which interface you'd get back at runtime. It's like expecting that a pizza or a soup to be delivered. It's one of them you don't know which until it arrives. Do you prepare a bowl or a plate for it?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I just updated my question trying to reflect the desired behavior.

Comment: @VLAZ for runtime the consumer of someVar would be selected similarly (dynamically). But i understand that this is a compiletime issue.

Comment: The consumer also using the same type "dynamically" doesn't solve anything. It's still exactly the same problem. Unless you never *ever* try to use the value and just pass it around in which case it doesn't matter what shape it has. However, consider `interface Interface1 { foo: string }` and `interface Interface2 { bar: number }`. If you *ever* try to do anything with `someVar` - do you use the key `foo` or `bar`? Do you use the value of the key as string or number? You cannot know *because it's dynamic*. You don't know until the code runs. It's the plate/bowl issue.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, they must type check it before using it but they can still use it?

Answer (score 0):

No. Javascript inherently is dynamically typed. Think of Typescript as a superset of Javascript with types. Types are not a run time concept. So there are actually no types in JavaScript. All the types disappear of the time of typescript compilation.

Comment: This should probably be a comment

Comment: @RuanMendes If something cannot be done then saying so is a perfectly valid answer. Comments are not for answering.

Comment: @VLAZ The question is unclear. It's impossible as stated but as others have mentioned, generics are functions that return types. Proving a negative is really hard and I would guess this answer doesn't help anyone who's trying to do what the OP actually wants to do. I think the lack of upvotes even from you and the upvotes on my comment kind of prove my point. You also did the right thing and asked follow-up questions instead of blurbing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A generic with a condition type could do what you want :

```
interface Interface1 {};
interface Interface2 {};

const desiredFunction = <T>(name:T): T extends 'name1' ? Interface1 : Interface2 => {
// define 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBGZBvAXwG4AoUSWRFdCrCAJn2JJIQHsQBnMZAEwk7AoEXgDEAriARhgHZAF5kAHgAqAPgAUIOAFsIALhUBKfchXIIAD0ghenZAHJte7A%20QB%20NBko5kpmphUjPJq%20CTIEcjCYOJQIEzIcPZwIACeJAQkQA)